Permission ViewAllData depends on permission(s): ViewDataLeakageEvents, ViewPlatformEvents
My pipeline is failing when adding ViewAllData to a permission set, the following error is shown:

Permission ViewAllData depends on permission(s): ViewDataLeakageEvents, ViewPlatformEvents

The pipeline attempts to deploy our changes to a new scratch org with our existing metadata. You can see in my definition file below we enable both streaming events and forensics which I believe are related to the permissions required above.
This is my scratch org definition:
{
  "orgName": "Scratch Org",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [
    "API",
    "AuthorApex",
    "EnableSetPasswordInApi",
    "PersonAccounts",
    "ContactsToMultipleAccounts",
    "DevelopmentWave",
    "SharedActivities"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    },
    "accountSettings": {
      "enableAccountTeams": true,
      "enableRelateContactToMultipleAccounts": true
    },
    "opportunitySettings": {
      "enableOpportunityTeam": true
    },
    "quoteSettings": {
      "enableQuote": true
    },
    "pathAssistantSettings": {
      "pathAssistantEnabled": true
    }, 
    "currencySettings":{ 
      "enableMultiCurrency": true 
    },
    "enhancedNotesSettings":{
      "enableEnhancedNotes": true,
      "enableTasksOnEnhancedNotes": true 
    },
    "dynamicFormsSettings":{
      "enableFormsOnMobile": true
    },
    "nameSettings":{
      "enableMiddleName": true,
      "enableNameSuffix": true
    },
    "eventSettings": {
      "enableEventLogGeneration": true,
      "enableTransactionSecurityPolicies": true,
      "enableDeleteMonitoringData": true,
      "enableLoginForensics": true,
      "enableStreamingApi": true,
      "enableDynamicStreamingChannel": false,
      "bypassMeteringBlock" :false
    }
  }
}


See this: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000z0M0vAAE/viewall-permission-in-permissionset-fails-to-deploy

@TusharJadav Please convert this to an answer.

Added to the Answer.

You can try the workaround provided into the known issue:
Now add the ModifyAllData user permission (to be enabled, true) in the XML file and deploy the metadata
or
Manually aggregate the Source and Target objectPermissions to have no object missing before the deployment.

You need to add the following to the *.permissionset-meta.xml files that the deploy step is listing as having failed.
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ViewDataLeakageEvents</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ViewPlatformEvents</name>
</userPermissions>

Add this above where you see the ViewAllData setting
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ViewAllData</name>
</userPermissions>


This fails, it returns a Unknown user permission: ViewDataLeakageEvents error.

Yes, I've found the same. This works on a scratch org but not when attempting to deploy to sandbox.
